# Making a web server with Docker instances - What goes Where?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker, uwsgi

I just came across Docker a couple days ago and have been doing some research, but one thing is still a bit unclear to me.

In a video I watched by the creator of Docker, he likened this utility to a shipping container so that you could guarantee that your stack works as intended once set up inside.

But I'm seeing a lot of container images which are just a single part of the stack, i.e. an nginx image or a uwsgi image.

Basically I want to run a web server using python, flask, nginx, and uwsgi. They're all part of the stack so should they go in a single container or should certain parts be in their own container?

I'll have a MySQL server as well, and this seems more logical to run in its own container.

Apologies if this is a matter of opinion, but to me it feels like there is only one right way to go about this.

Comment: you should have a look at the docker hub https://registry.hub.docker.com/ for example https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/johanberglind/docker-flask-nginx/ and the associated Dockerfile https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/johanberglind/docker-flask-nginx/dockerfile/

Comment: @user2915097 I'd actually seen that one already, and that's also part of what confused me. According to the Docker documentation, you should ideally only have one service per container, which seems to nullify the original purpose of docker, which was to have a specific stack working together in a container (or so i thought). I've seen images like the one you linked to, where it has everything in a single container, but then official images have only a single service per container, ie. nginx container, uwsgi container, etc.

Comment: you can have several processes in a container, see supervisor and the doc https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: @user2915097 Thanks. Is there a right way to do it though? or is it just up to the user? From the link you posted: "Traditionally a Docker container runs a single process when it is launched, for example an Apache daemon or a SSH server daemon. Often though you want to run more than one process in a container. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers are treated as deployment units - which means you package an application (or part of an application) and all its dependencies into a docker container that can be deployed independently. Your application could be monolithic where your entire application fits into one container just exposing HTTP end points for the browser to access, or an application that is composed of sub-components that can be independently deployed and managed - something like microservices - that when put together form the complete application. In such a case, each independent sub-component would reside in a container of its own. So, the decision on how many containers and how many processes within a container depends on the composition of your application and the kind of scalability you want to achieve.

Docker containers are meant to run single processes, but of course you can work around it by running process management tools like supervisord. I'm not very familiar with the python stack you are talking about, but I could explain this to you in terms of a stack comprising of Nginx + Node + Redis. I have elaborated on a sample docker workflow with this stack in my blog post as well: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/

In my example used in the blog post, Nginx, Node and Redis run on separate containers. The reason being the following:

- I want to be able to scale my node application depending on the load. So it makes sense to run it on separate container that I can scale independently.
- I run Redis on a separate container which acts as a shared data store for my node containers.
- To load balance my node containers I run Nginx - again on a separate container - that can dynamically balance the load across the scaled out node containers. The load balancing configuration can also be dynamically updated based on the state/availability/health of the node containers. It would be ideal if I could implement a service discovery mechanism which dynamically generates the Nginx configuration based on the availability of the containers. So scaling up would just be a matter of adding additional containers, and fault tolerance (failure of some node containers) would be automatically handled as well.

You can find the code behind this docker worflow on my github repo: https://github.com/msanand/docker-workflow

You could try to draw an analogy from this to any other web architecture stack. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could like this, I made a public (and open source) Docker image with all the bells and whistles that you can use to build a Python Flask web application.

It has uWSGI for running the application, Nginx to serve HTTP and Supervisord to control them, so you don't have to learn how to install and configure all those to build your Python Flask web app.

It seems like uWSGI with Nginx is one of the more robust (and with great performance) ways to deploy a Python web app. Here are the benchmarks: http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers.

There are even some template projects you can use to bootstrap your own. And also, you don't have to clone the full project or something, you can just use it as a base image.

Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask/

GitHub: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

And about the "one process per container" debate, some say that this is one of the **key misconceptions** when you look at it from a microservices point of view: https://valdhaus.co/writings/docker-misconceptions/

Answer (score 1):

As others here have said, officially it is recommended to have one process per container, see
https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/

However, I think there is much debate about how much process isolation you need. One example that is closer to the full stack is the phusion passenger image (phusion/baseimage and phusion/passenger-docker)
that bundles, amongst other things, nginx, ruby and passenger. Some people hate this, others think there is a place for such images. Opinions expressed about this particular image and a linked article discussing it can be found here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7258009. I think that you can generalize a lot of what is said there to your case and that the variety of arguments supports the variety of image types you have observed.

Personally, I think the full stack vs single process debate is down to the requirements of what you are trying to achieve. If you worry about scalability the single process paradigm might be better for you. If you care about quickly bringing up a dev environment, it could be more straight forward to create/take a container that feels a bit more like a virtual machine.